# Styling with dynamically used class names and attributes in JS(React)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I wonder if there is a feasible way to implement something like that.
Say, I want to specify padding but I don't want to use inline styling and want to use classes instead. But I also don't want to specify all possible values in CSS.

Like I write:

```
<Container className="p25 m10" />
```

what can be rendered to the **self-generated** classes p25 and m10

```
<div class="p25 m10"/> /* Classes p25 and m10 are self-generated and have padding and margin */
```

or even

```
<Container p=25, m=10 />
```

rendered into the same or at least to

```
<div style="padding: 25px; margin: 10px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that there is a way to auto-generate a css class. But,
this your first option, are classes that represent some kind of pure css style, what you can do is create a class like this:

```
.p25 {
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```
<Container className="p25"/>
```

Your second option, are props that inside the functional component, through some logic, you will carry out the implementation, for example:

```
export default function Container({p, m}) {
  return (
    <div style={{padding: `${p}px`}, margin: `${m}px`}></div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I don't have class .p25 and don't want to have it (as described in my question). How to use class "p25"?

Comment: As for the second solution, it's not clear how to pass p and m into Container?

Comment: Why don't you use tailwind ? https://tailwindcss.com/

Comment: The second form is exactly the same as your second version of your post, they are React props

Answer (score 0):

install tailwind and config manual stuff into config file.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        '25': '25px',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then use it this way

```
<div class="p-[25]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: What if I want to use p-26? Should I provide a separate value for it too? How to provide a universal way for any value?

Comment: add '26' value to spacing. spacing: {
        '25': '25px',
        '26': '26px',
      } @mimic

Comment: My question was how to provide all the possible values automatically without entering them manually?